# How to add a bunch of arrays to a single array

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of individual arrays that get filled with data, but because I want to form a league table, I want to add all these individual arrays to a single array  called teams which I can then use to order in terms of points, but I don't know what (or if) there is a function that I can use to get my new array to look like this

```
//What I want it to look like

var teams[
{id: 1, name: "ACMilan", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
{id: 2, name: "ASRoma", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
{id: 3, name: "Atalanta", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
{id: 4, name: "Bologna", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 //and so on and son
];


//The individual arrays I want to use to create a single array
var ACMilan = [
{id: 1, name: "ACMilan", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var ASRoma = [
{id: 2, name: "ASRoma", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Atalanta = [
{id: 3, name: "Atalanta", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Bologna = [
{id: 4, name: "Bologna", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Cagliari = [
{id: 5, name: "Cagliari", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Chievo = [
{id: 6, name: "Chievo", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
```

Comment: Concat them: `var teams = ACMilan.concat(ASRoma).concat(Atalanta).concat(Bologna).concat(Cagliari).concat(Chievo).etc...`

Comment: Or `[].concat(ACMilan, ASRoma, Atalanta, Bologna, Cagliari, Chievo)`.

Comment: Even better, if the individual arrays were object's properties instead of variables, you could do that programmatically, without having to type the variable's names.

Comment: if using es6 let teams =  [...ACMilan, ...ASRoma,...Atalanta, ...Bologna, ...Cagliari,...Chievo ]

Comment: First question is why so many individual variables in the first place when you want them to be associated with each other. Probably a better way to set this up before creating all those variables depending on how they get populated

Comment: I was just curious if there was any way of getting this done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just push all array elements into an array if you are using ES6 it is very easy

```
var ACMilan = [
    {id: 1, name: "ACMilan", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var ASRoma = [
    {id: 2, name: "ASRoma", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Atalanta = [
    {id: 3, name: "Atalanta", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Bologna = [
    {id: 4, name: "Bologna", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Cagliari = [
    {id: 5, name: "Cagliari", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Chievo = [
    {id: 6, name: "Chievo", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];

var teams = [
    ...ACMilan,
    ...ASRoma,
    ...Atalanta,
    ...Bologna,
    ...Cagliari,
    ...Chievo
];

console.log(teams);
```

And if you are using ES5 then simple do this

```
 let team2 = [].concat(ACMilan, 
                  ASRoma, 
                  Atalanta,
                  Bologna,
                  Cagliari, 
                 Chievo);

 console.log(team2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this function:**

```js
"use strict";

var ACMilan = [
    {id: 1, name: "ACMilan", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var ASRoma = [
    {id: 2, name: "ASRoma", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Atalanta = [
    {id: 3, name: "Atalanta", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Bologna = [
    {id: 4, name: "Bologna", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Cagliari = [
    {id: 5, name: "Cagliari", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Chievo = [
    {id: 6, name: "Chievo", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];

var teams = [];

function createTeamArray() {
    for (var i = 0, max = arguments.length; i < max; i++) {
        teams = teams.concat(arguments[i][0]);
    }
}

createTeamArray(ACMilan, ASRoma, Atalanta, Bologna, Cagliari, Chievo);

console.log(teams);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need here to keep a single object in an array. Remove the array brackets.

var newArray = [ACMilan, ASRoma, Atalanta, Bologna, Cagliari, Chievo]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all window variables and check them by mask. If any variable looks like your team mask you'll add it's data to an array. I don't know if this code will start correctly on this page but it's okay on my local machine or in plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/ic5YsX8F8W0uSa4ePAL3?p=preview). Also you don't need to know all team names, just team object values for it's mask)

```js
"use strict";

var ACMilan = [
    {id: 1, name: "ACMilan", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var ASRoma = [
    {id: 2, name: "ASRoma", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Atalanta = [
    {id: 3, name: "Atalanta", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Bologna = [
    {id: 4, name: "Bologna", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Cagliari = [
    {id: 5, name: "Cagliari", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];
var Chievo = [
    {id: 6, name: "Chievo", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];

var teams = [];

function getTeams() {
    for (var keys in window) {
        if(Array.isArray(window[keys])) {
            if (window[keys][0].hasOwnProperty('id') && window[keys][0].hasOwnProperty('name')
                && window[keys][0].hasOwnProperty('GP') && window[keys][0].hasOwnProperty('W')
                && window[keys][0].hasOwnProperty('D') && window[keys][0].hasOwnProperty('L')
                && window[keys][0].hasOwnProperty('GF') && window[keys][0].hasOwnProperty('GA')
                && window[keys][0].hasOwnProperty('pts')) {

                var cache = false;

                for (var i = 0, max = teams.length; i < max; i++) {
                    if (window[keys][0]['name'] === teams[i]['name'] && cache === false) {
                        cache = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!cache) {
                    teams = teams.concat(window[keys][0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

getTeams();

console.log(teams);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var ACMilan = [
      {id: 1, name: "ACMilan", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
    ];
   var ASRoma = [
   {id: 2, name: "ASRoma", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
   ];
   var teams = [];
   teams.push(ACMilan);
   teams.push(ASRoma);
```

There are many different ways to do what you want. A simple solution, is just push each array using `teams.push()`. While Using `concat()` will create and return a new array, `push()` will just append a new element into the array.